# Cannot login to zabbix Server as "Admin"

Tags: zabbix

Just installed zabbix server on ubuntu, but i am unable to login as "Admin" without password, as the Doc stated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When installed, use user name Admin with password **zabbix** to connect as
>   Zabbix superuser.

From [here](http://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/manual/quickstart/login).

assuming you're using Zabbix 1.8

Comment: actually i found the solution, the username was "admin" as opposed to "Admin" ref: http://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/manual/installation/appliance